# Equalize to zero a different element of a matrix for each row without loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an `IxS` matrix called `numerateur` and I would like to set one element per row to zero. However, the column to which this element belongs changes for each row. I can do it with a loop but would like to use a more efficient method.

You can find my loop below:

`choice` is an `Ix1` vector containing, for each row, the column number of the element I want to set to zero in `numerateur`.

```
for i = 1:I
        rank1 = choice(i);
        numerateur(i,rank1) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the column indices to [linear indices](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/):

```
ind = (1:size(numerateur,1)) + (choice(:).'-1)*size(numerateur,1);
numerateur(ind) = 0;
```

**Example**:

```
>> numerateur = randi(9,5,7)
numerateur =
     8     7     8     3     2     8     4
     7     8     6     3     6     1     3
     8     9     5     5     5     9     5
     4     4     2     7     4     9     9
     1     6     7     3     8     7     9
>> choice = [2; 3; 6; 5; 1];
>> ind = (1:size(numerateur,1)) + (choice(:).'-1)*size(numerateur,1);
>> numerateur(ind) = 0;
>> numerateur
numerateur =
     8     0     8     3     2     8     4
     7     8     0     3     6     1     3
     8     9     5     5     5     0     5
     4     4     2     7     0     9     9
     0     6     7     3     8     7     9
```

Comment: In addition, we could also use `sub2ind` to create the linear indices: `ind = sub2ind(size(numerateur),1:I,choice)`

Answer (score 4):

Use implicit expansion to find logical indices:

```
numerateur(choice == 1:size(numerator,2)) = 0;
```

Alternatively you can use [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix to generate logical indices:

```
numerateur(sparse(1:I,choice,true,I,S)) = 0;
```

Comment: That is clever, implicit expansion to create a logical array for indexing. Not as efficient with large arrays as the other options, but very clear and simple.